# Firefox hangs on a long lasting operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an MVC application and I am using a gif to indicate loading by using JQuery.
The code below works okay on Chrome.

```
   // show loading 
   window.parent.loading(true);
   $.get('@Url.Action("getUserAccounts")', function (data) {
        $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data);
        window.parent.resizeIframe();
    });
```

However, in Firefox, the loading indicator freezes along with the whole page. Since the operation is not taking too much time, I tried to mock this by using a sleep function like that and the results were the same on Chrome and Firefox. While Chrome keeps playing the gif, Firefox stops playing it:

```
   window.parent.loading(true);
   $.get('@Url.Action("getUserAccounts")', function (data) {
        function (data) {
            function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) {
                    /* Do nothing */
                }
            }

            sleepFor(10000);
            $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data);
            window.parent.resizeIframe();
    });
```

I used w3schools' editor to see the difference:
[w3 try editor](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get)

I used this code below in both browsers for comparison:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("#showMe").show();
    $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
       function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
                    var now = new Date().getTime();
                    while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) {
                        /* Do nothing */
                    }
                }

                sleepFor(10000);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
<div id="showMe" style="display:none">
                                <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu3XilJ5BOiSGic/giphy.gif" />
                            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to mock it that way because I could not reproduce this issue on my local. It only happens in QA environment. The operation takes longer in QA and that causes Firefox to freeze.

On Firefox, once the code hits to $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data); function, the problem occurs. That's why I remove .html() function and replaced it with sleepFor function to make the JS engine wait on Firefox. My expectation was gif should keep playing as it does in Chrome while I wait for sleepFor function to end.

Comment: Does the code in the first code snippet (without calling sleepFor() ) work in both browsers?
The issue is your "busy waiting" sleepFor() function - it bogs down the browser's JS engine - that is why Firefox becomes unresponsive. Please use window.setTimeout() instead. Also you are missing end quote characters in your first 2 code windows.

Comment: The sleepFor() method just adds a new problem to your code without actually mocking a long running request.  Consider removing it and chaining the done(), fail(), and always() methods to your get request as shown in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).  "always" could be used to reset the wait cursor regardless of success or failure.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about end quotes. I updated the code. First code snippet is only works in Chrome. 

I tried done() function but it is not working for sleepFor() function. I tried to mock it that way because I could not reproduce this issue on my local. It only happens in QA environment. The operation takes longer in QA and that causes Firefox to freeze.

On Firefox, once the code hits to $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data); function, the problem occurs. That's why I remove .html() function and replaced it with sleepFor function to make the JS engine wait on Firefox.

Comment: I suggest to focus on the first code snippet (without sleepFor() nor setTimeOut()) and use the Firefox debug console (press F12 key) to figure out what kind of answer you get from the server on your get() request. So press F12, a sidebar opens, go to the "network" tab and look for the GET request that your code sends (each GET is a line, timing diagram to the right of it). Select it by clicking, another sub-window opens with details of the GET request - go to the "response" sub-window and inspect whether it is what you expect.

Comment: All your sleep function does is lock up the browser from doing anything.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your reply. That is true and that was what I meant. I just want a loading gif to be on the screen for a little longer. I am not manipulating dom, not updating anything. This is weird because this code works on Chrome but locks up the Firefox.

Comment: So you should use timeout to delay something, not a forced loop.

Comment: @epascarello You are correct but my point is not to delay something. I am trying to mock a long-lasting operation. You can replace my sleepFor function with 1 million rows of data operation (I know it is not a good way but it is what's happening on jquery html function for Firefox) Just try the link and the code for both browsers and you will see what I try to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the response data returning from get action and I found the solution. Returned html data contains 18 lines of scripts.

```
 $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data);
```

After that, I debugged the JQuery html and append methods and realized that script tags are making Firefox freeze in a for loop (domManip function). I resolved the issue by reducing the included scripts to my response but it is still a weird problem. All those scripts are working fine on Chrome but not on Firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the debug tip I gave in my comment. You could look at the final state of your page HTML `<head>` section in the F12 debugger in the "inspect" tab (after the GET and `jQuery.html()` call have finished). Anyway, this issue also demonstrates that it's risky to include arbitrary data from outside sources using `jQuery.html()` - it is a security risk as it may execute arbitrary code on the user's machine.

Comment: Most of those includes are coming from bundles. You are right about security risks, Firefox might be doing it for protection over unknown script files.

Answer (score 2):

First, replace

```
sleepFor(10000);
$("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data);
window.parent.resizeIframe();
```

with

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#usersAccountsDiv").html(data);
    window.parent.resizeIframe();
}, 10000);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout  for usage of `setTimeout()`.

Do not make busy-waiting loops like your function `sleepFor()` - this precisely bogs down the browser's JavaScript engine.

Then, I suggest to focus on the first code snippet (without sleepFor() nor setTimeOut()) and use the Firefox debug console (press F12 key) to figure out what kind of answer you get from the server on your get() request.

To do this, press F12, a sidebar opens, go to the "network" tab and look for the GET request that your code sends (each GET is a line, timing diagram to the right of it). Select it by clicking, another sub-window opens with details of the GET request - go to the "response" sub-window and inspect whether it is what you expect.